# Can a dragon be drowned in its own element?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons

All dragons have some type of resistance or immunity against certain materials and energy types.(fire, acid, electricity, cold, steel, adamantine).

Can we kill a dragon with the related element as a drowning condition? They have lungs right?
Lets say we want to kill a red dragon, can we make it drown in lava?

Answer (score 21):

Dragons do need to breathe (note that black dragons have the ability *water breathing*, indicating that a dragon without it can't breathe under water and is subject to drowning rules), so anything that asphyxiates them will kill them, regardless of the element. A dragon's resistance to damage of certain elements doesn't save them from needing to breathe, just from being directly injured by that element.

How long a dragon can hold its breath would just use the normal drowning rules, so how long depends on a dragon's Constitution score. (But there's nothing to stop a DM from house-ruling that dragon physiology works differently in their game's setting, so *caveat slayer*.)